# How to do pod load balancing with statefulset in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, logstash, load-balancing, filebeat

From the document, it can be found there is a `Stable Network ID` feature to use for `Pod NDS`:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id

I tried to do

## service.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: logstash
  name: logstash
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
    - name: "5044"
      port: 5044
      targetPort: 5044
```

## statefulset.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: logstash
spec:
  serviceName: "logstash"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.10.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2Gi
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args:
          - bin/logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf;
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: configmap-logstash
            items:
              - key: logstash.yml
                path: logstash.yml
        - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
          configMap:
            name: configmap-logstash
            items:
              - key: logstash.conf
                path: logstash.conf
```

## configmap.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap-filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
      - type: log
        enabled: true
        paths:
          - /var/lib/nginx/access.json

    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash-0.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044", "logstash-1.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044"]
      loadbalance: true
```

Filebeat is deploying into a daemonset use this configuration.

It can't work. From the filebeat's log got:

```
2020-12-22T02:10:34.395Z    WARN    [transport] transport/tcp.go:52 DNS lookup failure "logstash-1.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local": lookup logstash-1.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local: no such host
```

If use this config, it can work:

```
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044"]
```

Why it caused `DNS lookup failure` issue when use `Pod DNS` format? Is there any more conditions to use this feature? Then how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also note from the [StatefulSet documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id):

> As mentioned in the limitations section, you are responsible for creating the Headless Service responsible for the network identity of the pods.

So you are resposible for creating [Headless Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) for the pods, e.g. `logstash-0` and `logstash-1`.

Comment: Are `logstash-0` and `logstash-1` the service names? If name it as `logstash`, it can be LB? [Building a headless service in Kubernetes](https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8)

Comment: Yes that is the service names

Comment: But how does the different services know which pod in statefulset group to choose? Can it do balancing automatically?